# systemd cannot find user file on boot

Tags: command-line, bash, systemd

I'm trying to run a script on boot on Ubuntu 16.04.

I'm using systemd with the following command.

```
[Unit]
Description=ether miner
Requires=network.target
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/amdcovc fanspeed:0,1,2,3,4,5=70
ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/moe/Desktop/claymore_ether/start.bash

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I can run the file with `sudo systemctl start ether` after I've logged into the user.

However, it doesn't run the file on reboot because I haven't logged into the system yet.

I'm getting the following error.

```
● ether.service - ether miner
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/ether.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since တေး 2018-01-25 14:22:48 +0630; 5min ago
  Process: 1165 ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/moe/Desktop/claymore_ether/start.bash (code=exited, status=127)
  Process: 1142 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/amdcovc fanspeed:0,1,2,3,4,5=70 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1165 (code=exited, status=127)

ဇန် 25 14:22:48 miner1.local amdcovc[1142]: Setting fanspeed to 70% for adapter 1 at thermal controller 0
ဇန် 25 14:22:48 miner1.local amdcovc[1142]: Setting fanspeed to 70% for adapter 2 at thermal controller 0
ဇန် 25 14:22:48 miner1.local amdcovc[1142]: Setting fanspeed to 70% for adapter 3 at thermal controller 0
ဇန် 25 14:22:48 miner1.local amdcovc[1142]: Setting fanspeed to 70% for adapter 4 at thermal controller 0
ဇန် 25 14:22:48 miner1.local amdcovc[1142]: Setting fanspeed to 70% for adapter 5 at thermal controller 0
ဇန် 25 14:22:48 miner1.local systemd[1]: Started ether miner.
ဇန် 25 14:22:48 miner1.local bash[1165]: /bin/bash: /home/moe/Desktop/claymore_ether/start.bash: No such file or director
ဇန် 25 14:22:48 miner1.local systemd[1]: ether.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=127/n/a
ဇန် 25 14:22:48 miner1.local systemd[1]: ether.service: Unit entered failed state.
ဇန် 25 14:22:48 miner1.local systemd[1]: ether.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

And `/home/moe/Desktop/claymore_ether/start.bash` exists because I can run `/bin/bash /home/moe/Desktop/claymore_ether/start.bash` with no issue.

How can I make sure the systemd has access to `/home/moe` folder?

It seems the `/home/moe` folder hasn't been mounted by the time the systemd executed the command.

Thanks.

Comment: Is your home directory encrypted?

Comment: @muru, you are a genius!! yes home was encrypted.

Comment: Then there's not much you can do. You'll have to move the script and needed files out of your home directory